# How do I specify an AJAX response?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm dipping my toe into Rails3 / JQuery / unobtrusive javascript.  I've written a toy app that does everything I want with JS disabled, now I want to introduce javascript so the server doesn't have to refresh the entire page on every transaction.

Here's the NON-JS Controller/View environment for creating a new Toy:

### controller

```
class ToysController < ApplicationController
...
def new
  @toys = Toy.all
  @toy = Toy.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html               # new.html.erb
  end
end
```

### views

```
# ========== 
# file: views/toys/index.html.erb
<%= render :partial => 'list', :locals => {:toys => @toys, :target => nil} %>
<%= link_to 'New Toy', new_toy_path, :class => 'new' %>

# ========== 
# file: views/toys/new.html.erb
<%= render :partial => 'list', :locals => {:dj_monitors => @toys, :target => @toy} %>

# ========== 
# file: views/toys/_list.html.erb
<div class='table-div'>
  <div class='body-div'>
    <% toys.each do |t| %>
      <%= render :partial => 'toy', :locals => {:toy => t} %>
    <% end %>
    <% if target && target.new_record? %>
      <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:toy => target} %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Pardon any apparent complexity, but all _list.html.erb does is list all the existing toys, and if :target refers to a new record, renders the _form partial at the end of the list.)

```
# ========== 
# file: views/toys/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(toy) do |f| %>
  <div class='column selected'><%= f.number_field :sku %></div>
  <div class='column selected'><%= f.text_field :description %></div>
  <div class='column selected'>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', toys_path %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### ajaxification

What I'd like in the javascript enabled version is that clicking on the 'new toy' link (in index.html.erb) submit an XMLHttpRequest that returns *only the form partial*, which would be rendered in-place.  The posting of that form would be a standard remote => true transaction as well.

But I can't figure out how to get the server to return the form only.  I modified ToysController's new method to:

```
def new
  @toys = Toy.all
  @toy = Toy.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html               # new.html.erb
    format.js   { render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:toy => @toy} }
  end
end
```

... and enabled the :remote => true option in the [New Toy] link in the index.html.erb view:

```
<%= link_to 'New Toy', new_toy_path, :class => 'new', :remote => true %>
```

Now my proxy web debugger sees `GET /toys/new HTTP/1.1` with `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` (that looks right), but the response is `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified`

Why isn't it rendering _form.html.erb?

### update: avoiding '304 Not Modified' (non-)responses

There were two issues -- @Robin solved the main problem.  The other part was that I was getting a "304 Not Modified" response -- it was technically correct, since the server had already sent the form -- but made debugging difficult.

So if you're trying to debug javascript / ajax code, it can help to stick a call to 'expires_now' in your controller to force the server to re-send the page while you're debugging, like this:

```
def new
  @toy = Toy.new
  expires_now
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html ...
    format.js ....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def new
    @toy = Toy.new
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { @toys = Toy.all } #you only need to get all toys in this case (and you should add pagination)
        format.js
    end
 end
```

in new.js.erb

```
$("#some_div").append("<%= escape_javascript(render "toys/form", :toy => @toy) %>")
```

You would need to render the partial in the `format.js` if you did the request yourself:

```
$.ajax({
   success: function(data) {
       $("#some_div").append(data);
   }
})
```

Comment: I modified my controller and implemented a new.js.erb along the lines you suggested, and -- neat! -- I saw the server respond with the form as javascript (though it didn't render it).  But on subsequent clicks, the server responds with "304 Not Modified".  So two questions: can you expand on your last sentence on how to render the partial, and should I be concerned about the 304 Not Modified?

Comment: I think I understand the 304 Not Modified stuff -- while I'm debugging, I've added `expires_now` to my ToysController#new method to force the server to serve up the form.  Still trying to figure out how to get it to appear on the page, even though new.js.erb looks correct.

Comment: turns out that everything worked once I remembered correct punctuation: $("some_div") != $(".some_div").  (But see 'update' above for 304 Not Modified workaround.)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: edit: ok, great if it works! -- The response (js code in new.js.erb) should be executed. So you need to change the `$("#somediv").append...` to something that fits your html. Just to be sure, if you just write `alert('success');` in you new.js.html, does the alert box pop up?

Comment: oh, yeah -- that and more.  see https://github.com/rdpoor/righteous_ujs for the fruits of my labors (and your help).

Comment: Cool :) In your toys controller, you should not get all the toys for every action: `before_filter :find_toys, :only => [:index, ...]`. And you might want to use a before_filter to find the current toy too: `before_filter :find_toy, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` so that you don't have to repeat the same line in these actions.